# Serving a file with an expires header depending on when it was last modified

Tags: nginx, cache

In nginx is there a way to conditionally serve a file with different expires headers depending on when the file was last modified? For example, if `foo` was modified within the last week then I want it to expire in a few hours, otherwise I want it to expire in a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers are probably already supposed to have the functionality you describe, so, there's really not that much point implementing it within nginx.

Standard nginx has the [`expires`](http://nginx.org/r/expires) directive, which lets you use several kinds of static no-comparison offset-style expressions, but not the dynamic ones you describe.

I don't think any of the standard modules that are compiled by default into nginx can do what you request here — dynamic expires, with a varying offset depending on how long ago the file was modified.

However, there is an [`ngx_http_perl_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html), which is an official experimental `perl` module directly from the makers of nginx, which lets you use the resourceful perl language directly from within the nginx configuration file.

Note that this `http_perl_module` is not compiled by default for obvious reasons (obviously requires perl etc), and is considered highly experimental — use with care.

Comment: The Lua module should be built in, and that would work as well.

Comment: Not yet in nginx, but it's already available in the kernel.  So, yes, you could probably tie your [in-kernel lua-based kernel module in NetBSD](http://bxr.su/NetBSD/share/man/man9lua/intro.9lua) with the [bpf(4)](http://mdoc.su/n/bpf.4) interface, and look for packets requesting certain files, find their mtime in the [vfs(9)](http://mdoc.su/n/vfs.9) layer, and patch the `Expires` HTTP response header in the outgoing packets as you please.  Care to volunteer a bounty for the work needed to implement such a solution?